# Como pegar o valor de um determinado item do listview java android

Tags: java, android

Como eu pego o valor de um determinado item(TextView) do listview.

estou tentando algo como isso:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {

Object obj =a.getItemAtPosition(position);

String mensagem = "Cliente Selecionado: " + obj;

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mensagem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        .show();}
```

mas retorna o cliente selecionado  e não é isso que eu preciso. Lembro que no meu listview existem vários TextView

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De acordo com a documentação do [`AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html#onItemClick%28android.widget.AdapterView%3C?%3E,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29), a `View v` passada por parâmetro é a `View` do item clicado no `ListView`.

Logo para recuperar alguma `View` dentro deste item basta usar ela assim:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
    // Usar o v
    TextView tv = (TextView) v;

    // Buscar alguma view dentro deste item
    TextView tv2 = v.findViewById(R.id.idDoTextView);
}
```

Assim, se você utilizou o `Adapter` corretamente para preencher os dados dos item do `ListView`, logo seria bom acessar os dados do item do `Adapter` do que a `View` do `ListView`, dado que o `findViewById` é mais custoso que acessar o item.

Comment: Exatamente o que eu precisava, funcionou, valeu @wakim!